# Proof about divisibility and greatest common divisor that doesn't use Bezout's formula

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, alternative-proof, gcd-and-lcm

Suppose the $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ and $c$ divides $a + b$. Prove that $\gcd (a,c) = 1 = \gcd (b,c)$.

This is relatively easy using Bezout's formula. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/513965/suppose-the-gcd-a-b-1-and-c-divides-a-b-prove-that-gcd-a-c-1-gcd-b). But is there a way to do it without Bezout?

Comment: This is already answered by "SomeStrangeUser" , "Spock" and others at the old question you have linked, without using Bezout.

Comment: Ah, I did not see people adding non-Bezout proofs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume that $(a,c) \not = 1$ and let $p$ be a prime divisor of $(a,c)$. Then $p \mid c \mid a+b$, but as $p \mid a$ we have that $p \mid b$. But this contradicts the fact that $(a,b) = 1$. Therfore $(a,c) = 1$. Similarly $(b,c) = 1$

Comment: This (excellent) proof doesn't need to be a proof by contradiction. We know that $\gcd(a,c)\mid a$, and $\gcd(a,c)\mid c\mid(a+b)$; hence $\gcd(a,c)$ divides $(a+b)-b=b$, and so $\gcd(a,c)$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $b$. Therefore it's less than the greatest common divisor: $1\le \gcd(a,c)\le \gcd(a,b)=1$.

Comment: @GregMartin Yes, you're right there are more ways to prove this. Anyway I like contradiction more, because according to me in some way it gives us more freedom in the proof.

Comment: @GregMartin -- You meant that gcd(a,x) divides (a+b)-b = a, right?

Comment: Hmm, actually I mean it divides $(a+b)-\underline{a} = b$.